# Corrupted Excel file

Tags: microsoft-excel, file-corruption

I am having trouble trying to open an Excel file.  I get this message:

> The File format and extension of 'ABC.xls' don't match. The file could be corrupted or unsafe. Unless you trust its source, don't open it. Do You want to open it anyway?

Here's an image of the message:

[image]

When I click on Yes, the file opens, but like this:

[image]

Comment: It doesn't looks like native xls,xlsx or ods format. I afraid you got corrupted file. Try to check your file systems: right click on disk->properties->tools->Error-checking->Check now

Comment: About the 6th line down, there's a reference to ppt/slides/slide4.xml, so this has at least some relationship to something Microsoft.  That may just be some kind of embedded image or link in some other type of document, though.  But does it provide any clue?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few possibilities.  It could be an .xls file that got corrupted or it could be some other type of file that got the .xls extension incorrectly.  It could have been modified by malware.  There are other possibilities, also, like Excel is corrupted or having a hiccup.  So you need to rule out the different possibilities.  Things to try:

1. If you got the file from some other source (i.e., it isn't your own), see if you can get a new copy.
2. Run a scan with a virus checker.  If your own doesn't have an option to scan a file on demand, there are scanners you can download for free, or for a free trial.  There are also web sites that will check a file for you.
3. Close Excel, restart it, and try loading the file again.  If Excel was having a hiccup, the file may open normally.
4. Verify that Excel can open other files normally.  If not, the problem is with Excel and you may need to reinstall it or run a repair utility on it.
5. If it is another type of file, you may be able to determine its actual filetype by opening it in a text editor, like Notepad or Wordpad, and looking for header information, which would typically be near the beginning of the file.
6. If the file is corrupted, it might be at least partially repairable.  There are utilities to cleanup or recover corrupted MS Office files.  I've never used one, so I can't recommend a specific tool.  But there are some kinds of corruption that would leave the file unrecoverable.

Without much to go on, this is pretty general.  Many of these suggestions have been the subject of other questions, so trying to cover all of the possibilities in an exhaustive manner would be way beyond the intended scope of a question.  If you can provide more information about the file (where and how you got it, what you know about it, what's been done to it, whether it was always bad, etc.), people may be able to provide more specific help.  But this will at least get you started.